# Video download restriction

Tags: php, video

We have a website in PHP and need to make users only watch videos not downloading it by any way (IDM , or any other download manager).
Videos always come with this ext .mp4

Comment: create a dailymotion or youtube channel and upload your vids on it , get player from stand alone script provided to integrate it on your site, it's an easy way to avoid media player issues also if you need your player you can use library http://videojs.com/

Comment: Playing requires downloading. So you can have one without the other. If you are trying to restrict access. you need DRM.

Comment: if you can see below this link: https://shahid.mbc.net/ar/episode/153508/حرب-الورود-الموسم-1-الحلقة-1.html       you can watch but you can't download it

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to let stream the mp4 by PHP.

Let's say that you store your mp4 files in the folder *video*.

**Firstly, deny access to /video/* from outside with for example .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^video(.*)$ no-access
```

Now, it's impossible to request http://url.com/video/file.mp4

**Secondly, let PHP stream your mp4**

So you don't link to your files directly, but use like */download/video/id*.

Streaming mp4 with PHP with examples can you find here: http://www.tuxxin.com/php-mp4-streaming/

Comment: tried so but still same issue user can download video